# ng build --prod error

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I'm developing with angular4 and angular-cli.
Sometimes, the command, 'ng build --prod' doesn't work.
I waited for a long time and I could see this result.
[image]

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.10.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

Comment: error is clear, you have not enough memory in your server. if this happening many times,you can compile it and use rsync for transforming `dist` folder to your server

Comment: @HasanBeheshti, oh I didn't think about it. Thank you! I'm a beginner learning mean stack. If you don't mind, can I ask more? how to use rsync for transforming `dist` folder to my server?

Comment: sudo rsync -avz path-of-your-dist/ username@serverAddress:path-to-server-dist. Remember use `/` end of `path-of-your-dist`

Comment: see this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps)

Comment: @HasanBeheshti, Thanks for reply!  I compile using `ng build --prod` on EC2 server after I deploy. Is this right way to deploy?